# Running a python script in every 30 minutes using Crontab?

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to run a python script for every 30 minutes. For this, I am using crontab.
I am new to crontab, I read and to run a script for 30 mins I have to use a query something like this:

```
*/30 * * * * python filename.py
```

But where exactly I have to fire this command.

I tried,

```
crontab -e
```

and change the file into,

```
*/30 * * * * python filename.py
```

Can someone explain how can I use crontab properly?

PS: I want to run a script for every 30 mins on a server that I have created on AWS ec2 instance, is there any alternate solution?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: so what's the problem with your code?

Comment: It's a good idea to specify the full path to your `file.py` and to `python`. You can use `which python` command to get the full path to python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose I have a python file `test.py` with the contents

`print "hello"`

To schedule it to run every 30 minutes, use

```
crontab -e
```

Then edit to add

```
*/30 * * * * python /path-to-file/test.py
```

To check if cron ran succesfully

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Here, you will see in logs, lines like

```
May 31 14:25:01 shivam-PC CRON[17805]: (shivam) CMD (python /home/shivam/test.py)
```

Note: `print` statement might not show in logs, so use

```
*/30 * * * * python /path-to-file/test.py >> /path-to-file/out.txt
```

and then check `out.txt` for print logs.

An alternate solution would be to use [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/).

Comment: */1 * * * * python /Cron_Job/cronex.py  >> /Cron_Job/out.txt
For a minute I use this, I am not able to see any changes in crontab.

Comment: You may want to capture stderr to the output file as well with
*/30 * * * * python /path-to-file/test.py >> /path-to-file/output.txt 2&>1